# Metalness in ShaderMaterial in threejs

Tags: graphics, three.js, shader

I would like to know what's the best way to use metalness using a ShaderMaterial. With other threejs materials I can add metalness as a parameter and modify it from 0 to 1 and see the results but at the moment I'm struggling to implement it in my ShaderMaterial. Clearly I'm missing something because from what I understood when metalness = 1, diffuse term is 0 and specular term is the base color. This is the highlighted code so far (recreating golden material):

```
var materialParameters = {
        cdiff_red: 0.0,
        cdiff_green: 0.0,
        cdiff_blue: 0.0,
        cspec_red: 1.022,
        cspec_green: 0.782,
        cspec_blue: 0.344,
        roughness: 0.5,                     
    }       

    var uniforms = {
        cspec: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },
        cdiff: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },
        roughness: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },          
        spotLightPosition: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },
        clight: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3() },         
    };

    vs = document.getElementById("vertex").textContent;
    fs = document.getElementById("fragment").textContent;

    ourMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({ uniforms: uniforms, vertexShader: vs, fragmentShader: fs });
```

Then I update uniforms and do the computations in the fragment shaders. I already tried to merge uniforms from native materials but I can't get it to work, what am I missing? I'm pretty sure the metalness value of standard threejs materials refers to something I can't find

Comment: Have you considered to extend a built-in PBR material like `MeshStandardMaterial` via [onBeforeCompile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile)? For minor enhancements, it's often the best approach. Otherwise you should use the built-in shader chunks to create a custom material from scratch. In this way, you can reuse the existing PBR metalness/roughness shader code.

Comment: Not really because I'm working on a ShaderMaterial, is there a way to make it work with it? And yes, I'm currently trying to use shader chunks without success

Comment: How about sharing your current progress as a live example? Right now it's not possible to see from your shared code what's going wrong.

Comment: Is there an alternative to jsfiddle? Cause I can't get it working somehow

Comment: Sharing a git repo is also a good idea.

Comment: You're right! Here is the link: https://github.com/LeLeXD/Metalness.git, as you can see I have a custom ShaderMaterial and I tried, with onBeforeCompile, to merge the metalness from a native material. This is what I've done at the moment but I still can't figure out what I'm missing

Comment: It seems you are not using `onBeforeCompile()` correctly. It should be used to extend a built-in material. You are just merging uniforms which has actually nothing to do with this callback. Are you actually aware that `UniformsUtils` only cares about uniforms? It has no effects on the shader source code at all.

Comment: Umh ok, I think I got it now, I wasn't really aware of onBeforeCompile functionality. So the best way is to use a native material and extend it with my shaders through onBeforeCompile?

Comment: I would start with that option and see how it goes.